# Spring - manage transactions between restcontroller

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

***In brief***: I will push data to frontend modify and then submit. All these should be managed by a single transaction.

***In detail***: I am currently developing an spring+angular application in which data consistency is very important. I need to ensure data consistency with some kind of transaction management.

As most restful web applications data is retrieved by frontend and modified and pushed to the backend via rest controllers. Right here I need to be sure that any other client did not modify the same data after I pull it.

Afaik spring manages transactions only at backend(I might be wrong), but here angular side is the dark side of transactions.

***What I need to figure out***: In java(particularly in spring) world how this problem is solved.

***What I have found so far***:
Hibernate Versioning Data for concurrency control :
https://dzone.com/articles/version-based-optimistic

Comment: As you already figured out optimistic lock is a well-known solution for the exact case you mentioned. And adding version is the hibernate implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

as you explained, your front (angular) pulls the information, at that moment your front loses control over the records or database, so you cannot avoid the information from being modified by others. As there is no real link between the front components and the backend maybe you should consider to include in your database a column to control modifications, something like a "lock" state, but this is not a simply solution, it also carries another problems like for example: if someone wants to edit a record but suddently leaves or exits your front application the "locked" record may still in that state forever, so there are additional considerations and controls to implement.

Comment: solution for data that is leaved with lock might be versioning the data. I paste a blog link at question